Should I use stainless or galvanized structural screws for a deck?
I'm rebuilding my deck. 20 x 20, 10 foot spans in 2x10 joist between an h-beam structure. It goes over a garage entrance/car alley.
My local big-box store offers something called

Simpson Strong-Tie LUS ZMAX Galvanized Face-Mount Joist Hanger for Exterior 2x8

which I was planning to use for hangers. The only approved screws I can find are

Simpson Strong-Tie Strong-Drive SD CONNECTOR Screw 9 x 1-1/2 inch 1/4-Hex Drive, Mech. Galv.
Simpson Strong-Tie Strong-Drive SD CONNECTOR Screw 10 x 2-1/2 inch 1/4-Hex Drive, Mech. Galv.

Is this the right screw to use? Wouldn't stainless steel give me a better/longer lifespan? Or is the use of a galvanized hanger making it moot anyway?

Sometimes using different metals together causes problems/reactions, mainly with plumbing and some electrical.  So using galv screws on gavl plates is good, where stainless or other metal might be bad.

Simpson has manufactured building ties and associated anchors for decades. Don't you think they have some experience to lean on?
They are reputable and I would rely on their recommendations rather than a guess.  Besides if conditions are such that the galvanized hanger deteriorates, what is the  stainless screw going to hold?
